# How to set a community User as the Delegated Approver

Tags: approval-process

I'm trying to select a Community User as another Community User's Delegated Approver but none of the Community User's show up.  I have gone through the profile and tried to find anything that might allow me to do this but can't find anything.  Is there something I need to enable to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting it from the Approver Settings section under the Personal Settings:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_change_approval_user_pref.htm

You can also update the delegate approver from a CSV file using the Data Loader (using the User Id field and the Community User Id in the DelegatedApproverId field)

Comment: Dataloader just gave me an idea to write a line of code to do it.  that worked!